# Domain Network: Users receiving "Invalid URL" or "Your Connection is not Secure"

Tags: browser, dns, google-search

I am having an issue that is affecting multiple users on my Domain.

Whenever I try to navigate to www.google.com I am unable to connect, I either get Invalid URL or Your connection is not secure.

I have tried checking my clock, it appears to be fine and is handled by the DC.

Also, I have tried clearing all my Cache on Google and I have done an:
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew

This did not fix the issue either.

Whenever I went into my IPv4 settings and changed my DNS to googles (8.8.8.8) I was able to connect and everything worked as normal, but in doing so I lose access to my Domain resources so this is not really a fix...

This issue has been coming and going a lot over the past few weeks, but as it never seemed to affect more than one user I didn't much bother with it. However, it seems to now be affecting more than one user at a time so I need to figure out what is going on...

Also, I have tried in different browsers.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have a corporate proxy or filter inline on that network?

Comment: No, we don't use anything like that here.

Comment: ok next question is what dns servers are you using when its not working? (the full dns hierarchy if you dont mind) sounds like something odd is going on. Is this a windows network? server? what version?

Comment: We are using a Windows Server 2003 Edition machine for our DNS. Is it possible to continue this conversation via e-mail?

Comment: Hmmm... that's *very* old and unsupported you know? can you access google from the server console ok ? Sadly I cant do off forum discussions - and you don't have access to chat on here yet. When you can access google what does a dns lookup on google.com give? vs when its working

Comment: I'm not sure how to check these things. How would I access from the server console (Do you mean can I go to google.com when at the machine?) Also, are you saying to change my DNS to googles DNS under my adapter properties? and then do an nslookup?